# text-decoration: underline ignored

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to style a list group so that group item text is not underlined. Some of my site css already includes

```
a:link, a:visited {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

For some reason

```
style="text-decoration: none;"
```

gets ignored.

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Link 1</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Info about link1. Underline this text.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Link 2</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text" style="text-decoration: none;">Info about link2. Don't underline this text.</p>
  </a>
</div><!-- list-group -->
```

CSS (from elsewhere on my site)

```
a:link, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbPbqQ?editors=110)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. it will give Underline to Link 2 and not for your item text

```css
a:link, a:visited {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.nounderline{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.underline{
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
    
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Link 1</h4>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">Info about link1. Underline this text.</p>
 </a>
    
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item nounderline">
  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading underline">Link 2</h4>
  <p class="list-group-item-text nounderline" >Info about link2. Don't underline this text.</p>
 </a>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. I wonder if there's a way to accomplish this without using the "!important".

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're applying the `text-decoration: none` inline-style to the `p` element.

Change to:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" style="text-decoration: none;>
  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Link 2</h4>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">Info about link2. Don't underline this text.</p>
</a>
```

Notice how the `a` tag now has the style, not the `p` tag. Works perfectly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGMGdN

Comment: Thanks, but I do need Link 2 to stay underlined.

Comment: Ahh, it makes more sense now

Comment: No problem. I should have stated my question more clearly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CSS.

Your CSS doesn't work because are using specific a pseudo-classes, where the inherited styles are addressing more than the specific pseudo-classes you identify.

Your original code:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The inherited code from other styles:

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Change your code to this:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and it works properly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdMdzZ

Comment: Thank you, but I can't change the global CSS file because that would affect the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with specificity and also applying the style to the wrong element. Make sure you apply it to the `a` tag. For example, give the tag it's own class and apply the CSS to that.

```
a.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOaOgO

Comment: Thanks, but I do need Link 2 to stay underlined.